# Can i make a define constructor which contains an object from another class?

Tags: c++

Can I do an defined constructor which contains an object from another class?
If i can do how is defined.
this is an example.I do classes and how could be defined the constructor of class "Abonati" which contains an object "abonament"
I need that because i have another class which contain a vector of "abonati"

```
#pragma once
#include"abonament.h"
  #include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class abonati
{
char*nume_abonat;
int nr_telefon;
char *numefisier;
abonament *a;


public:
abonati();
abonati(char*, int , char *,abonament *);
abonati(abonati&a);
void Send();
~abonati();
};


 `#pragma once
     #include"abonati.h"
     class abonament
     {
     protected:
    int cost;
    public:
    abonament();
    abonament(int costa);
   virtual ~abonament();
     };
  #include "abonament.h"
```

> 

```
 abonament::abonament()
{
this->cost = 0;
}

 abonament::abonament(int costa)
 {
this->cost = costa;
 }
 abonament::~abonament()
 {
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to pass an class instance to another class constructor

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int value) : m_int(value) {}
    int  GetInt() { return m_int; }
private:
    int m_int;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A& a) : m_int(a.GetInt()) {}     // Here constructor expects instance of class A
    int  GetInt() { return m_int; }
private:
    int m_int;
};


int main()
{
    A a(2);

    B b(a);    // Pass an object of class A to constructor of class B

    std::cout << b.GetInt() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
2
```